# Prevent VPN client from network scanning on ocserv

Tags: debian, security, vpn, firewall, openconnect

I have a ocserv server for VPN on a debian11 server.
One of my clients did a network scanning and service provider blocked my IP for terms of service violation.

This is 2nd time that this happened and I don't know who did this.
I want to ban the network scanner by myself but first I need to prevent further violations.
Is there anyway I can stop my clients from doing a network scan?

I tried to implement fail2ban but sounds like fail2ban is not a good tool for this issue.

Are there any other tools to prevent and block network scanning from clients of VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following [rules](https://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/recipes-ocserv-firewall-iptables-ipv4.html) to prevent or block network scans.